# Is it faster to load files on the Web simultaneously than sequentially?

Tags: http, caching, optimization, parallel-processing

I wanted to load images into my site in a certain order, but found that to slow down the total download time of my site.

Is it faster to load files simultaneously, on the Web, rather than sequentially?
Why?

I found this to be helpful, but didn't answer my question completely:
http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rules_intro.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the sweet spot to be around 4 sequential downloads.  Any more and you don't see much improvement in speed.  To get this you will need to define 4 different sub-domains to grab the files.  Browsers don't usually download multiple files from the same server.

Comment: Original question actual asks about putting files "into my site" but this answer seems to address downloading content. However the original limit in rfc2616 has been upped by most browser developers over the past 8 years - most now ill happily open up to 16 connections.

Comment: That's correct, browsers will open up more connections; however, a single TCP connection can be used to grab multiple files.  Each connection takes some time to setup, so depending on the scenario, having more connections may not end up in a faster download.

Answer (score 1):

There are better ways to optimize image loading.  You can use CSS Sprites to actually reuse the same image file in multiple places but use positioning and clipping to only show part each time.

You can also use delayed loading so you only load images that are shown on the screen.

**CSS Sprites**

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites

http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

**Delayed Loading**

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Answer (score 1):

Part of the speed problem of sequential downloads is the connection setup must be done for each download.

If your web server is correctly handling pipeline requests then this isn't so much of an issue.

Another problem is that with a single download stream TCP starts out choppy (slow, too fast, not very fast, too fast, fast) before it settles into a steady download speed. Using multiple connections smooths that out so the peaks and valleys of each TCP session cancel out.